# HTML5 Audio Player has 206 but does not play

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio, mp4

The file path is correct and Network tab return's `206 Partial Content`

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
        <source id="audioSource" src="../tempdata/ClFn1JmOSBJpFfxIOJOjag6zQ.mp4" type="audio/mp4"></source>
        Your browser does not support the audio format.
    </audio>
```

[image]

[image]

Even though the content-type does mention `video/mp4`, the file is `audio/mp4` and it plays perfectly locally so the file is not corrupted either.

Answer (score 1):

The Problems was that the audio file was encoded with `AMR_NB` which the HTML5 Audio Player does not Support. The workaround was to switch to `ACC` which the HTML5 Player does support.

Comment: thank you for this. I was really scratching my head as the dev tools do not give any indication regarding whether the file is supported